# Running HTML/JavaScript code using CGI-Bin and Python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have two buttons that both require a call to CGI scripts in the CGI-Bin. Using simple xmlhttp in html I was able to call the scripts and have it working. However I copied my exact code, but this time using python and printing the HTML as seen below. However the buttons do not seem to work when been clicked... Do I need to do something differently?

```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   # enable debugging
   import cgi
   import cgitb
   cgitb.enable()
   print "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
   print
   print '''<!DOCTYPE html>
   ******More code and stuff******
   <h2>Change Status of Door</h2>
   <button style="height: 50px; width: 100px" onclick="lock()">Lock</button>
   <button style="height: 50px; width: 100px" onclick="unlock()">Unlock</button>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   var xmlhttp;
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

   function lock()
       {
           xmlhttp.open("GET","cgi-bin/lock.cgi",true);
           xmlhttp.send();
       }
   function unlock()
       {
           xmlhttp.open("GET","cgi-bin/unlock.cgi",true);
           xmlhttp.send();
       }
   </script>
   '''
   print '''
   </body>
   </html>'''
```

Comment: What's the path of your script? Do you see any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: "the buttons do not seem to work"? How?